# Accessing individual records from dataset received from Silverlight RIA service

Tags: ria, silverlight-5.0

I am a newbie to silverlight & wcf ria service and am only finding examples where the dataset received from calling the domain service query is bound to a datagrid. I want to be able to access each record individually, without the dataset being bound to anything. How may I do that or does every data in silverlight need to be bound? Example: I call getlocations() and then need to iterate through each record and get the geographical points associated with each location.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I was trying to access the records before they were finished being retrieved (the async operation was not complete). So I transferred the function that uses the data to the event handler of the domain service load method, and then the function worked okay.